# Resizing the window

Tags: java, swing

I have the following program. When I change the column size, and click on any of the center, left or right alignment button, if the column size is too high then everything changes. I want the window to increase in size and not have anything changed in the arrangement of the panels.
Could some one throw some insight.

```
package workingwithjtextfields;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;


public class WorkingwithJTextFields extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jtfMessage = new JTextField(100);
    private JTextField jtfColumn = new JTextField(5);
    private JRadioButton jrbLeft, jrbCenter, jrbRight;

    public static void main(String[] args) //Main program begins here.
    {
        JFrame frame = new WorkingwithJTextFields();//Instantiating an object.
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("Exercise 17.11");//Setting the frame title.
        frame.setSize(500, 110);//Setting the size.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Setting the location.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);// Default closing options.
        frame.setVisible(true);//Setting visibility to true.

    }//End of main program

    public WorkingwithJTextFields() {

        // jtfMessage.setColumns(100);
        final JPanel parent = new JPanel();
        parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 3, 3));

        final JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 0));

        p1.add(new JLabel("TextField", SwingConstants.CENTER));

        jtfMessage = new JTextField("Type anything", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jtfMessage.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jtfMessage.setColumns(30);
        p1.add(jtfMessage);

        parent.add(p1);

        JPanel jpRadioButtons = new JPanel();
        jpRadioButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        jpRadioButtons.add(jrbLeft = new JRadioButton("Left"));
        jpRadioButtons.add(jrbCenter = new JRadioButton("Center"));
        jpRadioButtons.add(jrbRight = new JRadioButton("Right"));
        jpRadioButtons.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Horizontal Border"));

        final JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 1, 1));

        p2.add(jpRadioButtons);

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 1, 1));
        p3.add(new JLabel("Column Size"));

        jtfColumn = new JTextField("60", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        jtfColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        p3.add(jtfColumn);
        Border lineBorder = new LineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1);
        p3.setBorder(lineBorder);
        p2.add(p3);
        parent.add(p2);
        add(parent);

        jrbLeft.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jtfMessage.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                        jrbCenter.setSelected(false);
                        jrbRight.setSelected(false);
                        jtfMessage.setColumns(Integer.parseInt(jtfColumn.getText()));
                        p1.revalidate();
                        p1.repaint();

                    }
                }
        );

        jrbCenter.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jtfMessage.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                        jrbLeft.setSelected(false);
                        jrbRight.setSelected(false);
                        jtfMessage.setColumns(Integer.parseInt(jtfColumn.getText()));
                    }
                }
        );

        jrbRight.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        jtfMessage.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                        jrbCenter.setSelected(false);
                        jrbLeft.setSelected(false);
                        jtfMessage.setColumns(Integer.parseInt(jtfColumn.getText()));
                    }

                }
        );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the column size of the field, you will need to call `pack` on the fields window to cause it to resize the window to the preferred size of the components that it contains

For example...

```
jrbLeft.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtfMessage.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                jrbCenter.setSelected(false);
                jrbRight.setSelected(false);
                jtfMessage.setColumns(Integer.parseInt(jtfColumn.getText()));
                p1.revalidate();
                SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(p1).pack();
                SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(p1).setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: was about to mention pack, but you did it before me;
kudos!

Comment: @Shingetsu Here's hoping it works ;) (actually I did test it, but you always cross your fingers with these things ;))

Comment: I only cross fingers when it comes to java. Especially when using AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean. (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java applications uses LayoutManagers to control this, if you want to control it 100% you will have to use a non-standard component like Netbeans' AbsoluteLayout, but then you will have to include its .jar in your application.